# tangent vector of manifold

Tags: manifolds

According to this Wikipedia site
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space

"We can therefore define a tangent vector as an equivalence class of curves passing through x while being tangent to each other at x."

and

"... equivalence classes of such curves are known as tangent vectors of M at x."

However, the figure below shows a tangent vector v on TxM, a plane *off* M. How can this vector v, a *straight line off M*, be an equivalence class of *curves on M*?

Comment: Let me try to understand you correctly. Are you saying the blue arrow labeled by v in the figure is *not* actually a tangent vector, instead it is just a naive or intuitive way to hint the idea, while a true tangent vector is literally a set of equivalent curves on the surface labeled by M?  In other words, in this 2d case, the tangent plan is *not* the plane in which the blue arrow lies, but an abstract space composed of all equivalent classes each for a set of equivalent curves having the same gamma'(0)? Thank you for the answer and a little further clarification!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$The blue vector in [Wikipedia's image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tangentialvektor.svg) is a representation of the *common velocity* at the point $x$ to an equivalence class of curves in $M$. To explain the sense in which the blue arrow "represents a velocity" we have to be honest about a certain "abuse of geometry" inherent such a diagram.

Cartesian three-space $\Reals^{3}$ has a *tangent space* $T_{x}\Reals^{3}$ at each point $x$, consisting of all velocities $\gamma'(0)$ of differentiable paths satisfying $\gamma(0) = x$. This tangent space is more-or-less naturally identified with $\Reals^{3}$ itself: We view each vector $v$ as the velocity at $t = 0$ of the path $\gamma(t) = x + tv$, or using Wikipedia's definition, with the set of differentiable paths through $x$ and having velocity $v$ at $x$. However, the manifold $\Reals^{3}$ and the tangent space $T_{x}\Reals^{3}$ *are not literally the same entity*.

The last point is clarified by considering *the family of all tangent spaces*, (the total space of) the  *tangent bundle* $T\Reals^{3}$, which we identify with $\Reals^{3} \times \Reals^{3}$. An ordered pair $(x, v)$ may be viewed as a tangent vector at $x$. The vector space structure (vector addition, scalar multiplication) resides only in the second component: For an arbitrary point $x$, for vectors $v$ and $w$, and for a scalar $c$, we have $(x, v) + c(x, w) = (x, v + cw)$. This is the only meaningful vector operation on pairs $(x, v)$. The manifold $\Reals^{3}$ is identified with the set of $(x, 0)$, a.k.a. the *zero section* of the tangent bundle. The tangent space $T_{x}\Reals^{3}$ is the set of pairs $(x, v)$ with $v$ in $\Reals^{3}$.

We're now in a position to explain the abuse of geometry mentioned earlier: The tangent bundle of $\Reals^{3}$ is six dimensional, and therefore vexing to visualize. We may, however, depict a tangent vector $(x, v)$ as the *arrow* in $\Reals^{3}$ from $x$ to $x + v$. In other words, we map the tangent bundle to Cartesian space by the mapping $(x, v) \mapsto x + v$. The velocity $(x, v)$, which lives in the tangent bundle, is now represented in the same Cartesian space containing the objects (typically curves or surfaces) that gave rise to the velocity we wanted to picture. Similarly, the "tangent plane" $T_{x}M$ in the diagram is a subspace of $T_{x}\Reals^{3}$; our conventional representation maps this plane to the plane through $x$ that "looks tangent" to the surface $M$. The vector space structure is defined geometrically by arrows based at the point of tangency. Strictly, this plane does not occupy the same space as $M$, either.

Moving beyond the scope of the question (as it were), if we tried to draw *two* tangent planes to $M$ at different points, the representations would generally intersect along a line, but the tangent spaces themselves do not intersect, because they are subsets of distinct tangent spaces of $\Reals^{3}$, and distinct tangnt spaces are disjoint.

---

The modern viewpoint of abstract manifolds defines tangent vectors as "data structures" generalizing the "classical" picture in Cartesian space, but in a way depending only on the manifold structure. (Particularly, geometers prefer not to think of manifolds as subsets of a Cartesian space, since that fixes additional structure.) "Equivalence classes of velocities of differentiable paths" is one idiom. But there are other definitions, such as *derivations* (first-order differential operators) on the algebra of smooth functions. The crucial feature, whatever the definition, is that tangent vectors *transform compatibly with the chain rule* under change of coordinates.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I totally understand your definition in the second paragraph: the tangent space at point x consists of all velocities ′(0) of paths satisfying (0)=, represented by the blue arrow. But, to come back to my original question, each such velocity ′(0) is not the same as an equivalence class of curves sharing the same velocity, as defined in the Wikipedia article. The former is a vector, the latter is a set of equivalent curves. As these two concepts are not the same, which one is the right definition of a tangent vector?

Comment: The thing is, a vector $v$ in the "familiar" sense uniquely determines an equivalence class of curves having that velocity; conversely, the equivalence class of curves having fixed velocity at $x$ uniquely determines a "familiar" vector $v$. Because both data transform the same way under change of coordinates, they're both acceptable definitions of a _tangent vector_ in Cartesian space. <> It's not that there's a "right" or "true" definition, but the "class of paths" definition is relatively concrete and makes sense in a general manifold. [...]

Comment: By analogy, we might ask "What is the right definition of the web browser Firefox: The GNU/Linux version, the OS X version, the Windows version...?" But "Firefox" is arguably a _set of capabilities_. As long as two implementations provide the same capabilities, they're "equally good definitions."

Answer (score 1):

The figure in Wikipedia has only motivational purposes. It depicts a two-dimensional smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$.

For smooth submanifolds $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ one can define a geometric variant $\tilde T_xM$ of the tangent space at $x \in M$ as follows:

Consider a smooth curve in $M$ through $x$, i.e. a smooth map $u: J  \to \mathbb R^n$, where $J \subset \mathbb R$ is open with $0  \in J$, such that $u(J) \subset M$ and $u(0) = x$. The tangent vector of $u$ at $t = 0$ is the (standard) derivative $u'(0) \in \mathbb R^n$. The *Euclidean tangent space* $\tilde T_xM$  is the set of all such $u'(0)$ where $u$ is a smooth curve in $M$ through $x$. In the Wikipedia-figure the blue vector is such a tangent vector. In fact, $\tilde T_xM$ is not contained in $M$ in this example, but it is what we intuitively understand as the tangent plane of $M$ at $x$.

In an abstract manifold $M$ (which is no submanifold of some $\mathbb R^n$) we can still consider smooth curves $u$ in $M$ through $x$, but there is no geometric definition of $u'(0)$ as above. So what can be done? Going back to a smooth submanifold $M \subset \mathbb R^n$, we see that tangent vectors in $\tilde T_xM$ are in $1$-$1$-correspondence with equivalence classes $[u]$ of curves $u$ in $M$ through $x$, where $u \sim v$ if $u'(0) = v'(0)$. This observation can be used to **define** tangent vectors in any manifold $M$ as equivalence classes of smooth curves $u$ in $M$ through $x$. Details can be found in [The motivation for a tangent space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2982185).

**Update:**

The OP correctly comments that for a submanifold $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ a geometric tangent vector $u'(0) \in \mathbb R^n$ at $x \in M$ is *not identical* with an equivalence class $[u]$ of curves $u$ in $M$ through $x$ having the same derivative at $t = 0$. There only exists a $1$-$1$-correspondence between these two types of objects.

It is, however, a philosophical question what a tangent vector **really** is. There are various technically different approaches to introduce this concept, but they are all equivalent.

1. For a submanifold $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ we can define the geometric tangent space $\tilde T_xM$ as  above. It turns out that there is a canonical isomorphism to the variant of the tangent space $T_xM$ based on equivalence classes of curves. Intuitively such an equivalence class of curves specifies a *velocity vector* on $M$ at the point $x$: All particles moving along any curve in a fixed equivalence class have the same velocity (direction + absolute value) when they pass through $x$. If the force keeping the particle in its path $u$ through $M$ would vanish at $t = 0$, then the particle would move further along the straight line going through $x$ in direction $u'(0)$.
2. On abstract manifolds $M$ it is impossible to define a definite "numerical" value $u'(0)$ of a curve $u$ in $M$ in through $x$, but we still can use the "equivalence classes of curves" definition. Thus we may regard this approach as more general, but perhaps less intuitive.
3. A third approach on an abstract $M$ is to define a tangent vector at $x \in M$ as a *derivation* at $x$ on the algebra $C^\infty(M)$ of smooth functons $f  :M \to \mathbb  R$. See your Wikipedia article. A derivation can be regarded as a generalized directional derivative as known from multivariable calculus. This approach is even more abstract, but it results again in an isomorphic tangent space.

All approaches have their benefits, and it would be inadequate to claim that one of them is the sole legitimate variant.

There are similar phenomena in many branches of mathematicas. For example, when we construct the real numbers as an extension field of the rational numbers, we can do it via Dedekind cuts or via equivalence classes of nested rational intervals or via equivalence classes of rational Cauchy sequences. The results are technically different, but all are isomorphic. So what **is** a real number? In my opinion this is not really important, the real numbers are characterized by their *properties* which do not depend on the specific construction.

Here are some related questions:

[Alternative concepts for tangent spaces of smooth manifolds and derivatives of smooth maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4386105)

[Equivalent definition of a tangent space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3508284)

Comment: Thanks Paul for the answer! I totally see what you said: "tangent vectors in ̃  are in 1-1-correspondence with equivalence classes [] of curves  in  through ". But the correspondence between A: tangent vectors and B: equivalence classes of curves does not mean A=B.  When you say "define tangent vectors in any manifold  as equivalence classes of smooth curves in  through ", do you mean a tangent vector is (1) an equivalence class of curves, or (2) the velocity/vector u'(0)=v'(0) they  share? Literally, a collection of curves is not the same as the velocity they share.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that they're trying to introduce the idea of defining a tangent vector, a think you'd normally think of as *sticking out* from the manifold, as an object *on* the manifold.

In other words, $v$ at $x$ is the thing you'd naively think of, but we're trying to think in terms of $\gamma$, a curve on the manifold *passing through* $x$.

More generally, a big theme in the elementary theory of manifolds is trying to get away from having to think of your manifold as being in some bigger space. This is just part of that.

Also keep in mind that there are multiple ways to define tangent vectors, so this curve-based method is just one.

Comment: Let me try to understand you correctly. Are you saying the blue arrow labeled by v in the figure is *not* actually a tangent vector, instead it is just a naive or intuitive way to hint the idea, while a true tangent vector is a collection of all equivalent curves on the surface labeled by M?

Comment: @Ruye I'm not really claiming that $v$ is *not* a tangent vector. (Someone may come along and correct me.) My main point is that I'm trying to make you aware of a general theme, which is that AFAIK modern differential geometry attempts not to rely on any sort of ambient space when defining concepts. The first two paragraphs under "Formal definitions" at that Wikipedia page are describing this phenomenon.

Comment: There may be some formalism in which $v$, in that image, can be interpreted as a tangent vector. I'm trying to say that if you want to get into the modern theory of manifolds, you will have to learn to think more abstractly. (Note that I'm not saying you should never think in terms of intuitive pictures.)

Comment: Thanks Novice for your patience! I am new and trying to learn the basic concepts such as tangent space. So let me rephrase my original question: (1) In the special case of the function f(x1,x2) illustrated in the Wikipedia figure, is the blue arrow labeled by v a tangent vector of the surface labeled by M?  (2) May I consider this 2D surface as a special case of manifolds? If so, is the blue arrow v a tangent vector, or instead more abstractly an equivalence class of curves on M form a tangent vector? I feel these two concepts are very different and therefore cannot be both true. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ruye (1) I think the answer is yes, but there may be other people here who can answer more confidently. (2) Yes, the surface is a manifold. Regarding the rest, I think this is tricky, but the best thing I can say is there is more than one way to define and think about tangent vectors, so asking things like "is the tangent vector X, or is it actually Y?" may not get you anywhere.

Comment: Thanks to Novice, Andrew, and Paul, for answering my questions. I realize the term "tangent vector" has multiple definitions, different from but closely related to each other. It can be a velocity vector, an equivalent class of curves with the same velocity, or even a differential operator. Also, the answers to a similar question posted below also help.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388144/what-exactly-is-a-tangent-vector