# Is a sub manifold of Euclidean space with the same tangent space at each point an affine subspace?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I have a smooth (not necessarily connected) submanifold $M \subset R^n$ of dimension $m$ with the property that the tangent space to $M$ at each point $p$ is "the same". Now I understand that in general it makes no sense to talk about equality of tangent spaces (just about isomorphisms) but in this Euclidean case by "same" I mean that if I translate each $T_p M$ to the origin by subtracting the vector $p$ then it's the same fixed $m$-dimensional subspace $H$ of $R^n$, independent of $p$. Here I'm using of course the usual global coordinates on $R^n$. If I'm wrong then please correct me.

**Question**: Does it follow that then $M$ is "parallel" to $H$? That is, that $M$ must be contained in a translate of $H$?  I think this is trivially true because if $M$ is contained in a translate of $H$ then its tangent space at each point meets the conditions I gave in the first paragraph. Thus, it "must" be $M$. I'd just like to know if my thought process is correct or if I've gone off the rails somewhere. Thank You.

**Edit**: Changed title to accurately reflect question, thanks to Ted Shifrin.

**Edit**: Again responding to a comment by Ted Shifrin, who pointed out that I proved necessity rather than the desired sufficiency. My idea was to show that **if** you have a manifold with the "same" tangent plane at each point **then** it is an affine subspace, much like if you have a curve in $R^2$ with the same derivative everywhere it's a line. So, I first specified that the tangent spaces at each point of $M$ must be the same, then observed that an affine subspace has that property therefore, by "uniqueness" (granted, I'm not quoting a specific result), $M$ *must* be (contained in) such a subspace. That was my thought process anyway, I realize it's a simple result but I don't want to make any mistakes.

Comment: A hyperplane has codimension $1$. But, yes, such a submanifold will be an *affine* subspace, a translate of a linear subspace, of dimension $m$. You argued necessity rather than sufficiency, but it's not too hard to prove that only an affine subspace has this property.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Yes, thanks, I realized after writing the title that hyperplane was incorrect (notice I didn't use that term in the body) but neglected to correct it. I will do that now. On your last comment, I am sure you're right (really) but my intention was to argue sufficiency; i.e. that IF a manifold has the "same" tangent plane at all points then it must be an affine subspace. I tried not to make any other (aside from dimension) assumptions about $M$. Could you possibly give a bit more explanation as to why I am arguing necessity rather then the intended sufficiency? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said that an affine subspace obviously has the property, and therefore — appealing to uniqueness somehow, I guess? — such a submanifold "must be" an affine subspace. I would start by thinking of the submanifold as the graph of a function over the linear subspace given by the tangent plane. (Tangent planes of submanifolds are ordinarily *linear*, not affine, subspaces.)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Yes, I actually did have a reference to uniqueness in my post originally but removed it because I wanted to put it differently. I am going to edit my post and explain what I meant. And thank you for your suggestion, I'm going to work through it.

Comment: You should post the correct proof as an answer. As I said, think of $M$ as the graph of a (smooth) function from $H$ to $H^\perp$, and choose coordinates so that $H$ is the $x_1\dots x_m$-plane.

Comment: It is not true if you allow non-connected $M$. For example, take $M = H_1 \cup H_.2$, where $H_1$ is an affine subspace and $H_2$ a translate of it. And if $M$ is connected, it is not always a complete affine subspace. Take an open subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Agreed, will do, although it may take me a bit of time.

Comment: @Paul Frost Yes, thanks, I can see that. I guess it's not quite as trivial as I first thought (this stuff never is). As to your second sentence, would you be kind enough to tell me where completeness comes in? I believe you are saying that even IF I assumed $M$ was connected the fact it isn't necessarily complete would invalidate the result?

Comment: @HerbF1978 The best you can expect (as you wrote in your question) is that $M$ contained in a translate of $H$. Each relatively  open proper subset of $H$ is an example when $M \subsetneq H$.

Comment: @Paul Frost At the risk of becoming annoying, I don't quite understand your last sentence (and I really want to). Are you saying that $M$ cannot be a relatively open subset of $H$? If so, then why, if not, then could you perhaps put it a different way? Thanks regardless for posting your followup comment.

Comment: @HerbF1978 I wanted to say that each relatively open subset $M \subset H$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ with the same tangent space at each point. This gives examples with $M \subsetneq H$. These are no affine subspaces as asked in the title of your question.

Comment: @Paul Frost So if I get you correctly, the crux is that $H$ is not an affine subspace (it's a linear subspace). Therefore if my questions had been: "Must $M$ be contained in an affine or linear subspace?" the answer would have been yes even when $M$ is a relatively open subset of $H$? That's fine, I'm not being picky, I just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: @HerbF1978 Let me make some more comments. (1) It seems that you understand the tangent space $T_pM$ as an affine subspace containing $p$. I suggest to understand it as a linear subspace $T_pM$; then $p + T_pM$ is your affine subspace. See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4421786. (2) With this interpretation you can say that $T_pM = H$ for all $p \in M$. (3) Then you can prove that a connected $M$ with this property is contained in a translate of $H$. You can of course assume w.l.o.g. that $0 \in M$ and get $M \subset H$. But in general you will not have $M = H$.

Comment: Yes, Ted Shifrin pointed this out and I do realize that the tangent space is a linear subspace. It's just that in my head I try to picture that space moving around the manifold (i.e. attached) and I am sloppy when I write. I understand an appreciate your other comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

Following a suggestion by Ted Shifrin: We can view $M$ as the graph of a smooth function $f: U \rightarrow H^\perp$, where $U \subset H$ is some connected open set. If we choose coordinates so that $H = (x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ we then have
$$ M = (x_1,\ldots,x_m,f^1(x_1,\ldots,x_m),\ldots,f^{n-m}(x_1,\ldots,x_m)) $$
for $(x_1,\ldots,x_m) \in U$. At each $p \in M$ the tangent space $T_pM$ is spanned by the $m$ vectors
$$ (1,0,\ldots,0,f^1_1(p),\ldots,f^{n-m}_1(p))\ldots (0,\ldots,1,f^1_{m}(p),\ldots,f^{n-m}_m(p));$$ this would be consistent with my original scenario if I had specified that $H$ was the $(x_1,\ldots,x_m,0,\ldots,0)$ plane. In that case we must have $f^i_j(p) = 0,\; 1 \leq i \leq n-m,\: 1 \leq j \leq m$. In other words, each $f^i(p)$ must be a constant function, call it $k_{i}$; therefore
$$ M = (x_1,\ldots,x_m,k_1,\ldots,k_{n-m}), x \in U$$
which, is an affine subspace (I hope I'm right here).

Now I have made the simplifying assumption that $U$ is open and connected. In particular, as Paul Frost has pointed out, if $M$ is not assumed connected then this doesn't quite work. Actually, this question comes out of some research in which eventually I will just need all this to be true locally, so that's OK.

My thanks to all who commented (and perhaps will comment), I hope I have this right but my math skills are unfortunately not what I'd like them to be, this resource is invaluable.

**Update**: After thinking about Moishe Kohan's comment, I realize a couple of things. First, if $M$ is disconnected then, as Paul Frost pointed out, this isn't going to work (which is consistent with the idea that in general a manifold is only locally a graph). There are also results (e.g. Proposition 6.32 in Lee's ISM) that give conditions under which a manifold is globally a graph. I am going to do research to discover the "bit more work" Moishe Kohan refers to: At this point I can only see two options. One is to apply a result like Lee's referred to above because I believe the assumption that $T_pM$ is the same at all points of $M$ implies that $\{p\} \times R^{n-m}$ can only intersect $M$ at one point. The other is to try to show that the graph function defining the manifold locally can always be extended because the derivatives are bounded, sort of like when dealing with the maximal domain of integral curves. I hope I am on the right track but will see and again appreciate the help that was offered.

**Final Attempt at Proof**: Taking into account the comments of the contributors noted above I have come up with the following statement and "proof". *Statement*: Suppose $M \subset R^n$ is a smooth, connected submanifold of dimension $m$. Further, suppose that at each $p \in M$ the tangent space $T_p(M) = H$, where $H \subset R^n$ is a fixed linear subspace of dimension $m$. Then $M \subset H + \{p_0\}$, where $p_0$ is any point of $M$; i.e. $M$ is contained in a translate of $H$. *Proof*: Fix $p_0 \in M$ and let $p^\prime \in M$ be any other point;  since connected manifolds are path connected (at least in Euclidean space) there exists a continuous curve $\gamma: [0,t] \rightarrow M$ connecting $p_0$ and $p^\prime$. This curve can actually be made to be piecewise smooth (here I'm drawing on posts seen on MSE), say $\gamma: [t_0 = 0, t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{n-1},t_n = t] \rightarrow M$, with $\gamma(t_0) = p_0,\; \gamma(t_n) = p^\prime$. But at every point $t$ at which $\gamma$ is differentiable we must have $\gamma^\prime (t) \in T_{\gamma (t)}M = H$ (we use one-sided derivatives at the endpoints). So $\gamma[t_0,t_1) \in \gamma(t_0) + H = H + \{p_0\}$; furthermore, since $H + \{p_0\}$ is closed and $\gamma$ obviously continuous, $\gamma(t_1) \in H + \{p_0\}$. Continuing in this fashion we conclude that $\gamma(t_n) = p^\prime \in H + \{p_0\}$. Noting that $p^\prime$ was arbitrary completes the proof.

As I say, this is my best effort. I hope I have gotten it "mostly" right but, as always, will take whatever criticism is leveled at me.

**Sorry, one more thing...** This is taking on a life of its own. I am aware that just because the tangent to a curve is everywhere contained in a hyperplane does *not* in general mean the curve "stays" in that hyperplane. I have had occasion to make use of Whitney's example of a curve not constant on a connected set of critical points; the difference is that in the example the domain of the function is an unrectifiable curve in $R^2$ while here the curve is the image of a subinterval of $R$ by a smooth (almost everywhere) function. So I waved my hands a bit on that one.

Comment: A priori, you can only locally view $M$ as a graph, so a bit more work is needed for a complete proof.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Thank you very much. Let me work on your comment a bit. I had originally thought of that (whenever I deal with manifolds my starting point is local) but realized that the result I needed was global, so dismissed it because of my belief that patching local results together can get tricky. Your comment tells me that I need to revisit my initial thoughts.

Comment: No, you are on a wrong track. You already know that locally your $M$ is contained in a parallel copy of some $m$-dimensional linear subspace. You just have to prove that this parallel translate is the same at all points.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Thanks for the guidance. When you're a mathematician then I'm sure this would be obvious or easily derivable, but I have to resort to being guided (hopefully only once) and then keeping this approach in memory for a possible "next time".

Comment: Maybe I will write a proper answer a bit later.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Well of course any contribution you make would be appreciated, but I think that with this last bit of guidance I can do it. I'd like to test my understanding, I will try to write a complete answer in a bit, although it may not be until later today or tomorrow because of time constraints.

Comment: Sure...........